# Magento Product Pages Request Timeout

Tags: magento-1.5

My product pages have recently started to take up to 50-100+ seconds to load. I have made no changes to my Magento code and, after speaking extensively with my host, no changes have been made server side (I think).

An example of an affected page:

http://www.blindssupreme.ca/index.php/shop/blinds/faux-wood-blinds/value-faux-wood.html

Pages that work:

http://www.blindssupreme.ca/index.php/shop/blinds/faux-wood-blinds.html

After investigating, I noticed that, upon visiting the affected page, CPU usage jumps to 100% (and basically bogs down the site for anyone else to view). In my system.log, I get the following message:

```
DEBUG (7): getPriceType::client
```

The affected Magento version is 1.5.1. We also don't really get that many visitors (no more than ~10 at any one time) so I don't think it's that.

Answer (score -2):

I see your pages it will take to much time to load the data.

first link open fast but subcategory detail page will not open an as fast as the main category. you are using Magento 1.5 it's to the old version of Magento. please Upgrade with Magento 1.8.1 so This issue will resolve automatically there are so many new features like cache Management as well as performance wise Up-gradation so It will Solve your problem.

Comment: that really doesn't answer his question, although upgrading to a new version might be a good idea anyway.

Comment: This question is ask more then 7 months ago that time magento 1.8 is going on. so i provide him this solution